# solrcloud backup issue when using shared folder

Tags: solr, backup, solrcloud

Dears need your help,
I have 3 sharded solr servers 
i'm request a backup using the below request

```
http://prod-01:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=BACKUP&name=SourcesIndexBackup&collection=SourcesIndex&location=file:////prod-01//f//solr//backup//&async=66
```

Servers:

prod-01 has the Shard2 replica

prod-02 has the shard1 replica

prod-03 has the shard3 replica

and when i check the status using :

```
http://10.0.1.4:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=REQUESTSTATUS&requestid=67
```

the result as below :

```
 {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1},
  "success":{
    "10.0.1.4:8983_solr":{
      "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":0}},
    "10.0.1.5:8983_solr":{
      "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":0}},
    "10.0.1.7:8983_solr":{
      "responseHeader":{
        "status":0,
        "QTime":0}}},
  "6734175562642099":{
    "responseHeader":{
      "status":0,
      "QTime":0},
    "STATUS":"failed",
    "Response":"Failed to backup core=SourcesIndex_shard1_replica_n1 because org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Directory to contain snapshots doesn't exist: file://sabr-prod-01/f/solr/backup/SourcesIndexBackup"},
  "6734175562231000":{
    "responseHeader":{
      "status":0,
      "QTime":0},
    "STATUS":"completed",
    "Response":"TaskId: 6734175562231000 webapp=null path=/admin/cores params={core=SourcesIndex_shard2_replica_n1&async=6734175562231000&qt=/admin/cores&name=shard2&action=BACKUPCORE&location=file://sabr-prod-01/f/solr/backup/SourcesIndexBackup&wt=javabin&version=2} status=0 QTime=0"},
  "6734175562508700":{
    "responseHeader":{
      "status":0,
      "QTime":0},
    "STATUS":"failed",
    "Response":"Failed to backup core=SourcesIndex_shard3_replica_n1 because org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Directory to contain snapshots doesn't exist: file://sabr-prod-01/f/solr/backup/SourcesIndexBackup"},
  "status":{
    "state":"completed",
    "msg":"found [67] in completed tasks"}}
```

only shared2 on server prod-01 is backing up ,

when i delete the backup folder and run the command though prod-02

```
http://prod-02:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=BACKUP&name=SourcesIndexBackup&collection=SourcesIndex&location=file:////prod-01//f//solr//backup//&async=66
```

then i get the following result

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":6},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],
    "msg":"specified location file:////sabr-prod-01//f//solr//backup// does not exist.",
    "trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: specified location file:////sabr-prod-01//f//solr//backup// does not exist.\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler$CollectionOperation.lambda$static$90(CollectionsHandler.java:767)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler$CollectionOperation.execute(CollectionsHandler.java:936)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.invokeAction(CollectionsHandler.java:223)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:210)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:177)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:745)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:726)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:507)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:378)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:322)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)\r\n",
    "code":500}}
```

which means that it cann't access the shared folder .

Notes :

1- I disabled firewall

2- I give Full Control permission to the shared folder for everyone .

Please i need you help to accomplish this .

what else i can do

Answer (score 0):

you are trying for your three shards to backup to the same (shared directory), don't do that. It should work if you use a local directory to each host. So:

1. create a backup target in each host, named the same
2. now use that target (that will address the local dir of each host)
3. I remember I had some issues until I got the backup to work in Solr 6, the docs were not perfect.But things should have been ironed out in newer versions I think.

Comment: These i have tried before doing the shared directory and it will not work